# VueJS set axios header persist

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I've had a problem which my vuex state's only lasts for web page refresh. Once web page is refreshed, data in the vuex store is vanished.

For overcome that I've used nice pluggin called [Vuex persistestate](https://github.com/championswimmer/vuex-persist) 
Now my vuex is persist.

But still I've a issue with the axios authorization header. I've set auth header in axios login action like this

```
actions: {
    login({ commit }, payload) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
          axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = payload.token;
          commit('setUser', payload);
          resolve();
        } catch (error) {
          reject();
        }
      });
    },
  },
```

But this auth headers value got undefined if I hit the refresh button. How do I overcome this problem?

Comment: try putting your header in the cookies and then take it from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because in the last session you called `login` and it saves the token in your axios instance. On refresh, the headers setting is gone. Vuex persisted state only save your Vuex, and your token is not in your Vuex.

I use [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) here.

```
// login action
   ...
   axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = payload.token;
   Cookies.set('token, payload.token);
   commit('setUser', payload);
   resolve();
   ...
```

```
// Put it somewhere in the entry of your application, e.g: `main.js`, `App.vue`.
axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = Cookies.get(token);
```